# IQueryable conditional GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

I am attempting to build a groupby based on condition however I have been unsuccessful.

```
IQueryable<MyObject> query ..
var returnedVal = query.GroupBy(y => new {
                            Val1 = !first ? y.Val1 : null,
                            Val2 = !second ? y.Val2 : null })
                 .Select(x => new MyObject {
                            Val1 = !first ? y.Key.Val1 : null,
                            Val2 = !second ? y.Key.Val2 : null });
```

| id | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | test1 |
| 2 | Danny | test2 |
| 3 | Elle | test2 |
| 4 | Elle | test3 |

Scenario 1: **first**: false **second** false
GroupBy both Val1 and Val2
Return all 4 rows

Scenario 2: **first**: true **second** false
GroupBy only Val2
Return 3 rows (test1, test2, test3)

Scenario 3: **first**: false **second** true
GroupBy only Val1
Return 3 rows (Sta, Danny, Elle)

Scenario 4: **first**: true **second** true
GroupBy nothing
Return nothing

My problem is that everytime either "first" or "second" is true Val1 and Val2 still gets included in the groupby of the query. Is setting Val1/Val2 to null in the GroupBy the right approach to exclude it from the groupby entirely?

Comment: As a side note, you might as well just do `.Select(x => x.Key)`, since you'll end up with the same value as what you've got there.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Can I use a single Key when I have two values in the groupBy?

Comment: Ah, never mind: I didn't notice the `MyObject` part of the `Select`. Maybe `Select(x => x.First())`?

Comment: Also, can you provide a minimal reproducible example, with sample input and output? It's unclear what kind of results you're expecting when `first` and/or `second` are true/false.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior added additional sample data

Comment: My problem is that even though "first" or "second" is true, they still get built in the query string for the groupby

Comment: @TheProgrammer: What are the expected results?

Comment: As a side note, you might as well just do .Select(x => x.Key)

Comment: "they still get built in the query string" - what does this actually mean? Do you understand what the `new { ... }` syntax does?

Comment: Also, why would you choose to have `first` and `second` be logically backwards?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the actual problem, because you don't tell if the result is what you expect. If you just want to remove the unnecessary grouping, use an `if`:

```
if(condition){ queryWithBothProperties } else { queryWithOneProperty }
```

The bool flags are not related to the records, so you can easily leave them out of the query.

On that way the query might become more efficient:

```
if (first && second)
{
    // no grouping necessary since all would be null anyway
    result = query
        .Select(x => new MyObject { Val1 = x.Val1, Val2 = x.Val2 });
}
else if (first)
{
    result = query
        .GroupBy(x => x.Val2)
        .Select(g => new MyObject { Val1 = null, Val2 = g.Key });
}
else if (second)
{
    result = query
        .GroupBy(x => x.Val1)
        .Select(g => new MyObject { Val1 = g.Key, Val2 = null });
}
else
{
    // both are false, you want to group by both properties
    result = query
          .GroupBy(x => (x.Val1, x.Val2))
          .Select(x => new MyObject { Val1 = x.Key.Val1, Val2 = x.Key.Val2 });
}
```